# put() not adding values into fstream

Tags: c++

I have been attempting to create a program that takes input from the user, both a hexadecimal offset, as well as value, and inserts it into a fstream. Initially this was working, however only with one value (00 to ff).

Now instead, I am attempting to convert a string into an int 2 characters at a time, and placing the value into the fstream using put(). It correctly gets the offset, correctly converts the string to an integer (from what I can tell), however it does not seem to put the value into the fstream.

```
void write_offset(fstream &in, int offset)
{
    string value;
    unsigned int size;
    ostringstream os;
    unsigned int replace_value;
    unsigned int pos;
    string pause;
    bool valid = true;

    in.seekp(offset);
    cout << "Enter Value: ";
    cin_flush();
    cin >>  value;

    for (char& c : value)
    {
        if (!isdigit(c) && !((c <= 'f' && c >= 'a') || (c <= 'F' && c >= 'A')))
        {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (valid)
    {
        size = value.length();

        cout << value << " " << size << endl;
        if (size % 2 != 0)
        {
            size++;
        }

        read_offset(in, offset, ceil(size / 2));

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (size / 2); i++)
        {
            stringstream buff(value.substr((i * 2), 2));
            unsigned int buff_val;


            buff >> hex >> buff_val;

            cout << hex << buff_val << " -> " << dec << buff_val << endl;

            in.seekp(offset + i);
            replace_value = read_offset_int(in, offset + i, 1);
            pos = in.tellg();

            cout << "Replacing " << replace_value << " with " <<  buff_val << " (offset " << (pos - 1) << ")" << endl << endl;

            in.put(buff_val);
        }

        cout << "Enter 'save' to save the hex edits you have done, or write if you wish to do another." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "There was a problem with your hex value! (" << value << ")" << endl;
    }
}
```

The output would look something like this:

```
Enter Offset: 3b
Enter Value: fe384ecd
fe384ecd 8
Value at offset (3b) (length 4): 00 48 01 00
fe -> 254
Value at offset (3b) (length 1): 00
Replacing 0 with fe (offset 3b)
38 -> 56
Value at offset (3c) (length 1): 48
Replacing 48 with 38 (offset 3c)
4e -> 78
Value at offset (3d) (length 1): 01
Replacing 1 with 4e (offset 3d)
cd -> 205
Value at offset (3e) (length 1): 00
Replacing 0 with cd (offset 3e)
```

However, even after using close(), there are no changes.

If any other code needs to be provided, I will do so, however I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere in this loop.

edit: Ok, I tried instead of reading input as a string, reading it as an integer (which originally worked). It seemed to work fine, but the reason for using a string is I want to be able to input multiple values. I have instead changed the code to the whole function.

Comment: The code of `read_offset_int` may be relevant, as well as showing how you created the stream - you're not checking for error codes either...?

Comment: How should I go about checking for error codes? I am still pretty new to all this. As for the read_offset_int, it doesn't actually change anything, merely checks what the hex values are at an offset. And lastly, for the stream creation: in.open(argv[1], fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);

Comment: What is the use of buff_str? Why not "buff >> hex >> buff_val"?

Comment: I had originally used that, however I couldn't use buff with cout. Either way, using just "buff >> hex >> buff_val" yields the same result.